The third parameter of PrintWindow API
Recently I am using a Win32 API called PrintWindow(), which can screenshot a specific window. In some windows that have enabled hardware acceleration, the image will be blank. However, if I change the third parameter from 0 to 3, it can work again.
I also posted a demo code written in C#:
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool PrintWindow(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hdcBlt, int nFlags);

public struct RECT
{
    public int Left;
    public int Top;
    public int Right;
    public int Bottom;
}

public static Bitmap GetScreenshot_PrintWindow(IntPtr hWnd, Rectangle screenBounds)
{
    RECT windowRect;
    if (!GetWindowRect(hWnd, out windowRect))
        return null;
    Rectangle windowBounds = new Rectangle(windowRect.Left, windowRect.Top, windowRect.Right - windowRect.Left, windowRect.Bottom - windowRect.Top);
    Rectangle intersection = Rectangle.Intersect(screenBounds, windowBounds);
    if (intersection.IsEmpty)
        return null;
    Bitmap screenshot = new Bitmap(intersection.Width, intersection.Height);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot))
    {
        IntPtr hdc = g.GetHdc();
        PrintWindow(hWnd, hdc, 3);
        g.ReleaseHdc(hdc);
    }

    return screenshot;
}

In the official documentation, Microsoft only lists PW_CLIENTONLY, and there is no much information about this parameter, so I am wondering what it is, what values I can use, and what their effect is.

The value you can use is the one that is documented.

Hi Ken White, as I said in my question, if you choose to use 1, it can not screenshot windows that enabled hardware acceleration, but if you use 3, you can get the screenshot again. I know the document only list 1, but what the parameter really does?

Yes, I'm aware of that, but the only allowable parameter is the one that is documented. The parameter is described in the documentation. Throwing random values at it is just poor programming.

The document is really unclear about the third parameter "drawing options", and there is little information on the internet, so I really want to know what will it do. I know it is always the best to use the "listed allowable value" when writing the program, but in some cases it would be really helpful to know the unlisted value.

But you can't know the unlisted value, because they are not documented, which means they don't exist as far as anyone outside the MS internal staff knows, and they're not allowed to reveal internal information. The values are not listed for a reason, which means that MS does not intend them to be used, and just tossing random values to API functions is a good way to damage or brick your system.

Yes, you are correct, but I still wondering what mean by "drawing options".

There is exactly one option listed, and that is the only one that can be used. If they're not documented, they either don't exist or they're not intended to be used.

@HanHan There is only 2 "drawing options" publicly defined - 0 (print the whole window) and 1 (print the client area only). The nFlags parameter is a bit field, and end users are allowed to use only bit 0 right now.  Microsoft reserves the right to add more flags, and In this case it sounds like there is an undocumented flag 0x02 that is intended only for internal use.

Duplicate of What parameter of PrintWindow() should be used?

what it is, what values I can use, and what their effect is. Maybe an incident would be helpful to you.

Non-duplicate related question: Issue capturing a bitmap using window handle in Windows 8

PrintWindow() is primarily for printing. If you need to take a screenshot of a window use the designated screen capture API.
